# Is it possible to view/download the content of the POST done via my facebook application?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a scenario, where an authorised user through my application is posting status/uploading pictures via my application by granting required permissions. My application uses graph APIs.

Now, as app administrator if I want to see the content of the post, that the user has uploaded via my application. How do i do it?

I know in graph APIs, I have INSIGHTS api. But, it just gives us the statistics of the posts done via my app or user.

Can i really see the posts?

Assuming as an app admin I only have app access token and app ID. I dont store user access tokens with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I worked on the problem with every possible way. Found out that, even being an APP administrator I will need user access token (stored with me), without which these data shall not be retrieved via APIs.

My need was not to use user access token; But, no Its not possible via APIs as of now.